# IIS7 and Enforce lowercase URLs

Tags: url, iis-7, url-rewriting

I tried to use option in iis7 Enforce lowercase URLs, but when i enabled it all images that had *.JPG extension (uppercase) stopped server. in prev version of iis it was ok when using upper and lower cases, it returned same source

may i fix it? or should i create rule for each extension like (jpeg, jpg, gif...)

Answer (score 1):

I was just reading an article on writing rules, from Scott Gu

[Tips/Trick: Fix Common SEO Problems Using the URL Rewrite Extension](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx/)

He talks about the issue of excluding static files (.jpeg, .jpg, .gif, etc.) from the lowercase rewrite, and shows how you can add conditions to exclude files.  Another article is where I found the condition for excluding more than just Scott's example

[Mike's Umbraco blog - URL Rewriting and SEO](http://umbraco.miketaylor.eu/2010/11/03/url-rewriting-and-seo/)

He adds the condition:

```
<add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(axd|css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$" negate="true" ignoreCase="true" />
```

I hope this helps you in future rewrites.