# How to format the URL of my ASP.NET MVC 5 website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a website and it's url appears on the browser llike this:

mysite.com/Produto/PaoDeMel

and for SEO reasons I'd like it to be like:

mysite.com/produto/pao-de-mel

but my actionname is PaoDeMel, and the framework doesn't let me use "-" on the name.

Is there a routing config or anything else to achieve my goal?

PS.: the solution suggested in [How do I change the url in MVC 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514890/how-do-i-change-the-url-in-mvc-5) didn't work for me.

Thanks

Comment: There is some guidance here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787053/iis7-and-enforce-lowercase-urls

Comment: How come `ActionName` doesn't work? The other approach would be to create a route that would capture the URL and have an action method that translates the url segment to some Id that corresponds to a product in your db.

Comment: You have to create your own `Routes`  look for "translating url in MVC"

Comment: Look into the 2nd answer in the link you provided using [Attribute Routing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IRouteHandler` and `IHttpHandler` interfaces (special attention on ProcessRequest method of IHttpHandler implementation):

```
public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new MyHttpHandler();
    }
}

public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Take routes values to build a url string that can be handled by "Default" route
        string url = "/" + context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower();
        url += "/" + (context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["part1"] as string).Replace("-", "").ToLower() + (context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["part2"] as string).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
        url += "/" + context.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];

        context.Server.TransferRequest(url, true);
        }
    }
```

Next, add routes that handle default and custom routing:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { action = @"[^\-]*" }
        );

    routes.Add("MyRoute",
            new Route("{controller}/{part1}-{part2}/{id}",
                new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "Home" }, { "action", "Index" }, { "id", "" } },
                new MyRouteHandler() // Custom route handler
                )
        );
}
```

No matter how many hyphens have your url in action segment (mysite.com/produto/pao-de-mel, mysite.com/produto/pao-de-mel-a-b-c, etc.), this will be captured by the "MyRoute" route, and will be processed by `MyRouteHandler` that will transform the path into a url that can be handled by the "Default" route, achieving this, by transfering the request to be processed by normal flow of ASP.NET MVC Routing.